# How to use WebLookup with log4j-web?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

I'm using the `log4j-web` dependency for proper (de)-registration of the `log4j2` logger in a `tomcat` environment:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Problem: then I cannot use `WebLookup` anymore as follows:

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="TEST" fileName="${web:rootDir}-${web:majorVersion}-application.log" ..>
```

When I exclude the `log4j-web` dependency, the weblookup works fine. But I have to use the dependency for proper tomcat logging.

Probably the lookup is initialized too late.
So, how can I still make use the weblookup?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: hook in before logger initialization, and populate the map params to use in log4j2.xml config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        MainMapLookup.setMainArguments(new String[] {"thekey", "thevalue"});
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
fileName="${main:thekey}-..."
```